# UNION on parameters SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have three parameters in my stored procedure. On two of them I execute a SELECT statement to retrieve a specific value. I want to use the third parameter to make a UNION on the first two parameters.
Basically this is how it looks kinda.

```
DECLARE @MaxDate1
DECLARE @MaxDate2
DECLARE @AllDate
SELECT @MaxDate1 = MAX(Date) FROM Table1
SELECT @MaxDate2 = MAX(Date) FROM Table2
```

This is what I would like however I can't figure out how to write the query in this case.

```
SET @AllDate = @MaxDate1 UNION @MaxDate2
```

Thank you for the help, or suggestions.

Well since I received lots of minuses I will try to explain how I tried to do the whole thing. I have a stored procedure where first I look up the latest dates from two different tables. After I look up the dates I create an IF ELSE statement stating that if the date selected by the user is bigger than the one in the database then it should return an error, however if the date is smaller than the MaxDate then all columns and rows should be returned up to the selected date. However the dates are dynamic so the query looks them up each time. Therefore it takes long to check the MaxDate and according to that to look up the fields also...the connection times out. So I was trying to make a union on the MaxDate of the two fields, and use the @AllDate as parameter to be checked to the selected date. Hope its a bit more clear :)

Comment: why do you need to store the value on `@AllDate` is it an output parameter?

Comment: do you want max of @MaxDate1 and @MaxDate2?

Comment: If you plan to have @AllDate as a date datatype you need a new plan.  Union queries can return more than one value.

Comment: well at the moment I get the date in the two first parameters, but then according to the last dates I should select some other values also, however when i run the code, the query times out since it first has to look up the latest date, and then starts searching for the other values.

Comment: Please specify how you would like to combine the two parameters. Concatenate them? Add them?

Comment: What do you mean about UNION of two date?

Comment: Just a second, I will try out the answers I received, then I will write more information about the code

Comment: Well since I received lots of minuses I will try to explain how I tried to do the whole thing. I have a stored procedure where first I look up the latest dates from two different tables. After I look up the dates I create an IF ELSE statement stating that if the date selected by the user is bigger than the one in the database then it should return an error, however if the date is smaller than the MaxDate then all columns and rows should be returned up to the selected date. However the dates are dynamic so the query looks them up each time. Therefore it takes long to check[...]

Comment: [...] the MaxDate and according to that to look up the fields also...the connection times out. So I was trying to make a union on the MaxDate of the two fields, and use the @AllDate as parameter to be checked to the selected date. Hope its a bit more clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the two date in a table structure for your PRC, then why don't you use a table, like this:

```
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE(
MaxDate datetime)

INSERT INTO @DateTable (MaxDate)
select max(Date) as Maxdate from Table1
union
select max(Date) as Maxdate from Table2
```

If you need to return the two dates for an other procedure or something for later use, I would recommand to use a [`TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), because then you can return a table, what you can use for your `SELECT` later.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMaxDates()
RETURNS @MaxDates TABLE
(
MaxDate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @DateTable (MaxDate)
select max(Date) as Maxdate from Table1
union
select max(Date) as Maxdate from Table2

RETURN

END
```

Comment: I never used TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION. Im gonna look into that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I extended with an example

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out and will return as soon as I manage to get it to work. Koszonom ;)

Answer (score 2):

Union is used to "union" to sets of data.

you can do something like:

```
select @maxdate1 as Maxdate
union 
select @maxdate2
```

Though you do not need all this as you can do something like

```
select max(Date) as Maxdate from Table1
union
select max(Date) as Maxdate from Table2
```

on a scalar, you cannot use union.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just write this:

```
SELECT @MaxDate1 AS MaxDate1, @MaxDate2 AS MaxDate2
```